# refresh token without client_id and client_secret

Tags: web-application, api, jwt, oauth2, permissions

I was reading the OAuth protocol docs https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6 where it implies that you don't need a client_id and client_secret to refresh an access token, just a grant_type and the refresh token.

I was of the believe that in a situation where your refresh token is compromised, an attacker may not have your client id and secret therefore won't be able to get new access token even if they send a request to your server for one.

What am I missing here? Isn't the risk greater when you don't need extra layer of security checks to get new access tokens?

For context: This is for a Django application that uses Django rest framework for API support and simplejwt for API protection. Authentication is handled using CAS.

Comment: The authorization server has to validate/authenticate the user when refreshing a token.  That's done outside of any claim in a token.  The refresh token may also be set to one-time use.  Only the content/resource server trusts claims held in a token.

Answer (score 1):

The section that you quoted contains the following statement

> If the client type is confidential or
> the client was issued client credentials (or assigned other
> authentication requirements), the client MUST authenticate with the
> authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.

and also gives an example with an `Authorization: Basic` header. To me this implies that the client *does* need `client_id` and `client_secret` to refresh the token (in the form of the basic authentication).